# How Processing knows that user is pressing multiple key at the same time?

Tags: processing, keycode, ctrl

I have no idea how Processing knows that a user is pressing `Ctrl` and some character at the same time.

Multiple buttons at same time only. Is it possible?

ex: (`Ctrl+r`).

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first check if Ctrl has been pressed. If it has been pressed then you save a boolean as true. The next time you press a button you check if the button is the button you want (i.e. 'r') and if the boolean is true. If both are true then Processing knows...

Here's a demonstration:

```
boolean isCtrlPressed = false;
boolean isRPressed = false;
void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  if (isCtrlPressed) background(255, 0, 0);
  if (isRPressed) background(0, 255, 0);
  if (isCtrlPressed && isRPressed) background(255, 255, 0);
}
void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == CONTROL && isCtrlPressed == false) isCtrlPressed = true;
  if (char(keyCode) == 'R') isRPressed = true;

}
void keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == CONTROL) isCtrlPressed = false;
  if (char(keyCode) == 'R') isRPressed = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old feed, but I have something that might help everyone with multiple key presses. This is for Processing's Python Mode, but I'm sure it can be implemented in some way for other modes.

```
import string

#string.printable is a pre-made string of all printable characters (you can make your own)
keys = {}
for c in string.printable:
    #set each key to False in the keys dictionary
    keys[c] = False

def keyPressed():
    #If key is pressed, set key in keys to True
    keys[key] = True

def keyReleased():
    #If key is released, set key in keys to False
    keys[key] = False
```

And then using multiple if statements, you can check the dictionary for whether the key is pressed or not.

```
if keys['w'] == True:
   #Do something
if keys['s'] == True:
   #Do something
if keys['a'] == True:
   #Do something
if keys['d'] == True:
   #Do something
if keys[' '] == True:
   #Do something
```

And so on.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could also override the keyPressed(KeyEvent) method and use the KeyEvent.isControlDown() method:

```
void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
  println(ke.isControlDown());
}

void draw(){
  //need draw() method for keyPressed() to work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find out the "key" codes of any combination of "ctrl + *" or "Shift + *" by typing, but this method is not suitable for multi-clicking to control the game.
combination search code

```
void setup()
{
  textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  text(int(key),50,50);
}
```